# Как сделать кнопку постоянно активной?

Tags: javascript, функции

Делаю переключение языков на сайте через 2 кнопки, есть отельный файл с переводами каждого класса, при нажатии на кнопку язык переключает без ошибок, но всего на долю секунды. Как решить?

```
buttonUA.addEventListener('click', changeURLLanguageUA);
buttonEN.addEventListener('click', changeURLLanguageEN);

// Перенаправляет URL с указанием языка
function changeURLLanguageUA(){
 let lang = buttonUA.value;
 location.href = window.location.pathname + '#'+lang;
 location.reload();
}
function changeURLLanguageEN(){
 let lang = buttonEN.value;
 location.href = window.location.pathname + '#'+lang;
 location.reload();
}

// Функции перевода
buttonUA.addEventListener('click', function() {
 hash = buttonUA.value
 for (let key in langland) {
    document.querySelector('.lng-' + key).innerHTML = langland[key][hash];
  }
});
buttonEN.addEventListener('click', function() {
 hash = buttonEN.value
 for (let key in langland) {
    document.querySelector('.lng-' + key).innerHTML = langland[key][hash];
  }
});
```

Comment: Если вы уж на js это делаете, не лучше ли переводить язык без обновления страницы? У каждого элемента с текстом есть же свой идентификатор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас два обработчика клика на каждую из кнопок. Один обработчик переводит данные, другой - перенаправляет.  Получается, что вначале успевает один сработать, потом происходит перезагрузка страницы. Вы определитесь что вы хотите. Скорее всего вам надо перевод данных делать не по клику на кнопку а после перезагрузки страницы, т.е. на событии `DOMContentLoaded`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    ... тут код    
    ... считываем хэш из URL     
    ... вызываем функцию перевода с передачей туда значение хэша
    ... ПРИ ЭТОМ ФУНКЦИЯ ПЕРЕВОДА ОСТАНЕТСЯ ОДНА....этого достаточно
});
```

Comment: Из текста понял, что можно просто удалить перезагрузку страницы и всё должно работать, верно?

Comment: Ну если это поможет - то да) Если всё должно работать без перезагрузки - вполне.

Comment: Спасибо, навели меня на такое банальное решение, с событием DOMContentLoader ещё не работал, поэтому попробую и с ним реализовать

Comment: Ну если перезагрузка не нужна, то клика достаточно и DOMContentLoaded не нужен. Но в целом описание события почитать полезно будет.